# Convert text to Image & Rotate It

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

is there a way i can convert text into Image & then Rotate it & then display it all using script\code to display in the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, take a look at GD's [`imagettfext`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) or Imagick's [`annotateImage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script, which you embed in your html-page like an usual image:

```
<img src="rotatedtext.php?text=blablubb" />
```

Don't forget to set the content-type of the http-header in that script to image/png (I recommend png for that purpose) before outputing the png-data:

```
//create the image here and then:
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
```